# How to refactor git branches

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I think I've done something dumb with my git branches. Thankfully, right now I'm the only one committing anything, so it's only me who has to deal with it, but I'd like to fix it before other people have to deal with it.

What I think I want it this:

```
                                               (today)                (the future)
main           *--------*-----*--------------*-----*-----             ------*--------------------*----     ...
                \       ^     ^              ^     ^                       /                    /
                 \      |     |              |     |                      /                    /
static-dev        *-----*-----*-----*--------*-----A-----     ...     ---*                    /
                                     \       |     |                     |                   /
                                      \      v     v                     v                  /
                          wp-dev       *-----*-----*-----             ---*-----*-----*-----*
```

Where "A" = 7890397

Not only is that what I think I want, it's what I thought I created. However, it seems not. So, the question is, how do I turn what I have into that (preferably historically, so the commit history makes sense; but at least into the future). What I *have* is this:

**EDIT**: the below is updated, because, as @torek and @omer-tuchfeld pointed out in the comments, there were problems with two local repositories being differently synced with the remote. With some rebasing and merging, I fixed that, so it should be less confusing now, but still needs "refactoring" (not sure what else to call this).

```
$git branch -a
* main
  static-dev
  wp-dev
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/static-dev
  remotes/origin/wp-dev
$git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline
*   fc56f21 (HEAD -> main, origin/static-dev, origin/main, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'static-dev' of [origin] into static-dev
|\ 
| * 7890397 commit "A"
* | d8f79a1 duplicate of "A"
* |   2dfd02c 
|\ \
| |/
| * 14e1877 
| * f75bfc6 
* | 34b885e 
* | f86807a 
* | 1a8d0ac Removed STUFF
|/ 
| * 74e522a (tag: v0.99.3, origin/wp-dev) "A" cherry-picked
| * 5439ac8 
| * 0a2c1d7 
| * 9174d5c STUFF should be here
|/ 
* 1886f04 (tag: v0.99.2) 
* 1b8dcad 
* 3448f5e Added STUFF before realising it should be on a branch
* b5e1fa5 
* b38ebe0 (tag: v0.99.1) Initial commit.
```

Because I messed up the order in which I should have done things (see 3448f5e, and 1a8d0ac), if I now make a change to static-dev and try to merge it to wp-dev, the merge deletes all the STUFF. I guess, notionally, what I want to do is pick up 9174d5c and everything that happened on that branch afterwards, and hang it off of 1a8d0ac; but I'm not sure how to do that, nor even if that is the most sensible solution to get things in a reasonable state.

Comment: Something that confuses me here: this must be *two different Git repositories* (with some shared commits) because in one we have a name `wp-dev` as well as a name `origin/wp-dev`, and in the other we have only an `origin/wp-dev`. Some commits seem to appear in both repositories, and others are only in one of them.

Comment: Also `origin/static-dev` is pointing at `7890397` in the second log and pointing at `14e1877` in the first log

Comment: Hmm.
`$pwd
/www
$git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/static-dev
  remotes/origin/wp-dev
$git remote -v
origin https://github.com/idapartners/website.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/idapartners/website.git (push)
$cd ../dev
$git branch -a
  main
* static-dev
  wp-dev
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/static-dev
  remotes/origin/wp-dev
$git remote -v
origin https://github.com/idapartners/website.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/idapartners/website.git (push)`

Comment: @torek yes, this confuses me, too — but look at the output I put in the comment above.

Comment: OK, so in `/www` there is one Git repository and in `../dev` there's a second Git repository, with the same remote—but that means you *do* have two different local Git repositories. Each one could be out of date with respect to the third (remote) Git repository over on GitHub. That would seem to be the case given what @OmerTuchfeld noted.

Comment: What does "hang it off of" mean?

Comment: 9174d5c is the start of the wp-dev branch, branched off of main. But it "should" be branched off of 1a8d0ac, the start of static-dev.

Comment: It's worth noting that (at least at the moment) there are no changes on wp-dev to files that exist in static-dev; there are only "new" files. But the problem is, from a commit history perspective, the new files actually existed before static-dev was created, and were then deleted from that branch.

Comment: "9174d5c is the start of the wp-dev branch, branched off of main. But it "should" be branched off of 1a8d0ac, the start of static-dev" Ok, that's an easy one. Rebase.

Comment: @matt I can't seem to figure out a rebase invocation that works. If I checkout wp-dev and rebase --onto 1a8d0ac, it doesn't bring over the files that exist in wp-dev (because they exists on main before wp-dev was created), but were removed in 1a8d0ac.

Comment: Sorry but we seem to have suddenly changed the subject. You asked for a topology of commits. Now we are suddenly discussing files. It is again completely unclear to me what the goal is.

Comment: My sorry :) The goal is to get to a state where I have a master branch (main), a development branch (static-dev), and a far-future dev branch (wp-dev), such that changes made to static-dev can be merged in the normal way both to main and to wp-dev — and to get to that state from my current mess (as shown in the git log). I was optimistic rebase would do it, but if it can, I can't get it to work because of the missing files problem.